# Run a function to upload xml within a Playwright(TypeScript) after tests are finished and test result xml file is generated?

Tags: typescript, playwright

Is it possible to call a function within a Playwright(TypeScript) test project after tests are finished and test report xml file is generated?

In my project, I'd like to import test result file to Jira, which need send a POST REQUEST to specific Jira endpoint, but looks like generating test result xml file is almost the very last step in the task of `npx playwright test`.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from Playwright team, see https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/28852#issuecomment-1877469630

Basically, custom reporter could solve this problem